# Is it possible to handle a matrix with strings and numbers?

Tags: python

I am a beginner, self-taught.

I am wondering if a matrix filled with strings and numbers can be made in python? Something similar like handle it in bash?

The type of matrix (14 rows x 14 columns) that I would like to handle is:

```
,,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
,,C,O,O,C,H,H,H,C,C,H,H,H
1,C,0.0,1.205475107329386,1.3429319010227962,2.3430136323519886,3.22738313640333,2.640130058756468,2.6401484355574363,1.4784953771865779,2.4427526711622995,3.4404701049315856,2.6506415109695562,2.173942147030341
2,O,1.205475107329386,0.0,2.245467917547002,2.6443156030953032,3.702905546101439,2.6354536594179083,2.6355724561170515,2.3918864536893496,2.871975783234887,3.9479515489105172,2.5936449600745437,3.2896946757332293
3,O,1.3429319010227962,2.245467917547002,0.0,1.418915551312475,2.015476882415432,2.0693088134923188,2.0692958839669946,2.3236193736523485,3.560975969980456,4.431347320573397,3.951843753512012,2.4366421143893597
4,C,2.3430136323519886,2.6443156030953032,1.418915551312475,0.0,1.0868846056358739,1.0921261760040055,1.092126228351473,3.6419246237091034,4.772348473634059,5.725281935435472,4.948741644534887,3.855293676517857
5,H,3.22738313640333,3.702905546101439,2.015476882415432,1.0868846056358739,0.0,1.7916118321336392,1.7916073980710447,4.336840746006843,5.570012200282658,6.44436962662531,5.876935928592363,4.304036910039309
6,H,2.640130058756468,2.6354536594179083,2.0693088134923188,1.0921261760040055,1.7916118321336392,0.0,1.774322615322816,3.999843247699306,5.001451201004137,5.992370839831868,5.038926795069471,4.349546588337786
7,H,2.6401484355574363,2.6355724561170515,2.0692958839669946,1.092126228351473,1.7916073980710447,1.774322615322816,0.0,3.9999029642804302,5.001556219427222,5.992449776200327,5.039085741282741,4.349558376763068
8,C,1.4784953771865779,2.3918864536893496,2.3236193736523485,3.6419246237091034,4.336840746006843,3.999843247699306,3.9999029642804302,0.0,1.324770443414403,2.107792016824585,2.085364895492881,1.079295724832157
9,C,2.4427526711622995,2.871975783234887,3.560975969980456,4.772348473634059,5.570012200282658,5.001451201004137,5.001556219427222,1.324770443414403,0.0,1.0763707503087891,1.0781013610472885,2.1192372863195152
10,H,3.4404701049315856,3.9479515489105172,4.431347320573397,5.725281935435472,6.44436962662531,5.992370839831868,5.992449776200327,2.107792016824585,1.0763707503087891,0.0,1.8418880170159488,2.4949700018092598
11,H,2.6506415109695562,2.5936449600745437,3.951843753512012,4.948741644534887,5.876935928592363,5.038926795069471,5.039085741282741,2.085364895492881,1.0781013610472885,1.8418880170159488,0.0,3.067298402780731
12,H,2.173942147030341,3.2896946757332293,2.4366421143893597,3.855293676517857,4.304036910039309,4.349546588337786,4.349558376763068,1.079295724832157,2.1192372863195152,2.4949700018092598,3.067298402780731,0.0
```

Comment: Yes, you can use a list of lists for this.

Comment: Pandas and numpy are the typical data science libraries for python where matrix stuff is handled. Pandas stands for panel data, and numpy stands for numeric python. You can read your file in to pandas as a dataframe and do all sorts of manipulation: `import pandas as pd` and then `df = pd.read_csv('path/data.csv')` to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data comes from a csv file, you can use the standard `csv` module:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader('data.csv')
matrix = list(reader)
```

or you can use `Pandas` package (pip install pandas or conda install pandas)

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are manually entering the values in the form of a matrix, you can simply use **Numpy Arrays** for having multiple data types into one by setting dtype as object.

```
import numpy as np

# 1D Matrix
matrix = np.array(['d',1,'e','c',2,5],dtype='object')

# 2D Matrix (as per your case)
matrix = np.array([[1, 's', 2], ['h', 4, 6]],dtype='object')
```